# SQL Loader unable to load CSV file data into linux environment correctly

Tags: linux, oracle, sql-loader

i was able to load the same comma delimited csv file's data into window oracle database correctly but in linux environment, the record being inserted having weird behavior. For example, the data being inserted are having a behavior like \n. i selected the record and paste it out notice that the record is like this

```
"data
"
```

the control file i used is as below

```
Load DATA
REPLACE INTO TABLE TABLE_NM                             
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
TRAILING NULLCOLS
```

please advice what i can do to make this scenario right. thank you in advance

Comment: Please provide some lines of sample data from the CSV file.

Comment: probably you're using the wrong format. New line character is different in windows and unix. Change the format and try again.

Comment: @JSapkota the sample data are as followed

a,b,c,d
a1,b2,c2,d2
a3,b3,c3,d3

this is what i got for the csv file, this is how it looks like when i try to open the file with notepad++

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After investigation, notice that the root cause of the issues is the feed file is not generated from Linux base environment. So after I manually convert the file into Linux version, the feed file is able to load into DB without any issues.

Answer (score 1):

Its the classic issue where on *nix systems lines end with a linefeed, but on Windows lines end with a carriage return/linefeed.  Since your data ends with carriage return/linefeed it is read fine on Windows, but Linux loads the carriage return.

You can either preprocess the data file and replace the line (record) termination character with a utility like `dos2unix` or change the control file by adding the `STR` clause to the `INFILE` option to set the record termination character to the carriage return:

```
INFILE "test.dat" "STR x'0D'"
```

I would opt for running the data through `dos2unix` to keep the control file more generic and not data filename specific.

Comment: i did not use INFILE command, where should i put the STR x'OD' thing then?